# When using blur with timeout to achieve click-outside-close - the time interval sometimes too short

Tags: javascript, settimeout, onclicklistener, blur

I have small widget that has a list of links, which can open and close:

```
<div class="widget">
    <input class="focuser">
    <a href="javascript:;">View options</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So, when I click on `View options` - list appears, and when click on any option - do stuff and close list of options.

And I need to have `click-outside-close` functionality - when user clicks anywhere outside just close the list.

I achieved this by focusing an invisible input when showing the options, and on `blur` of the input - hide the options after some timeout. This way:

1. when user clicks outside - the blur timeout runs out - hide the options.
2. if user clicks any option - clear the timeout, hide options & do
       stuff.

And the problem now is that sometimes the timeout ends before the click. I increased the timeout interval to 200ms, but it's still not 100% sure, and also - this way user sees delay before the options list close.

Any idea how to fix and/or improve this?

EDIT:

This is simplified version of the JavaScript code:

```
CartSidebar.DwCustomSelect = Ember.View.extend({

    blurTimeout: false,

    focusOut: function(e) {
        if (e.target.className == 'focuser') {
            var self = this;
            this.blurTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                clearTimeout(self.blurTimeout);
                $(self.element).removeClass('opened'); // hide options .. 
            }, 180);
        }
    },

    click: function(e) {

        var clickedElement = e.target;

        clearTimeout(this.blurTimeout);
        if (clickedElement.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li') {
            $(this.element).removeClass('opened'); // hide options .. 
            doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I created a plunker, so you can see it in action:

https://plnkr.co/edit/boA6yC0sEbLAZU9tjyso?p=preview

(I did the timeout too small, so you see the problem. But even if you increase the interval - you'll see that the `focusOut` triggers before the `click`.)

Comment: Why do you need a timeout? Why not just hide the list immediately after clicking outside the list?

Comment: Just like @MattSpinks said, get rid of `setTimeout`. If you insist on having the delay using `setTimeout`, then post your code to see where is the problem.

Comment: Because in the case you click on option - the sequence will be `blur of input` - `hiding options` - `click` - but the options won't be there, so `click` triggers on the element below the options.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a functionality where you need to hide your div when user clicks anywhere except that div then you can add a click listener to whole document with the code to hide div.

```
var a = document.querySelector("a");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
a.addEventListener('click', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
if(ul.classList.contains('show')){
    ul.classList.remove('show');
    ul.classList.add('hide');
}else{
    ul.classList.remove('hide');
    ul.classList.add('show');
}   
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(){
    ul.classList.remove('show');
    ul.classList.add('hide');
});
```

For detail example check the jsbin below

http://jsbin.com/mamexev/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I was thinking of such solution too - globally listen to the document `click` - but the widgets is actually an `Ember` view, and it has it's own `click` handler, that I was/am supposed to use. That listener is bound to the top level element of the widget. This is where I'm checking if an option is clicked and clear the timeout from the input.

Comment: Could you update your question with your current javascript code you have written to blur and hide list?

Comment: Sure. I just did :)

Comment: I added a plunkr also.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout thing is one option. But you must define a large interval because it will depend on how fast the browser processes everything. It will work 99.99% of the times, but it's not bulletproof, as you said.

Other trick is to listen to the blur of the *whole thing*. If you assing a `tabindex` attribute to an element, it will receive focus events. If you set `tabindex="0"` it will get an automatic index and you won't have to worry about it.

So, instead of listening to the blur of the `input`, listen to the blur of the `div` `.widget`. When the focus goes from the input to the link or the `li`s, it will be still within the focus of `widget` and the `blur` event won't fire.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but when I click on an option from the list - the parent element looses focus, although it has `tabindex`. I debugged and saw that the focus goes to the clicked element - the option from the dropdown.

Comment: Yes, the focus changes but the `blur` (or `focusOut`, is the same for this matter) event *of `.widget`* shouldn't fire (`blur` of the input will fire). You just have to listen to the proper element's events. Please, post your code to check on it if that isn't the problem.

Comment: I edited my question earlier today and added my JS code. Is it OK, or you want to take a look at something else? :)

Comment: Yes, I meant the try you did with the `tabindex` suggestion.

Comment: I added a plunkr also.